# Updating time offset with moment().utcOffset()

Tags: javascript, express, time, momentjs, utc

I'm facing some issue trying to use `moment.js` for dealing with time offsets.

I collect in an hidden input the local user time offset:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('input#timeoffset').val(moment().utcOffset()); 
  });
</script>
```

The offset gets correctly stored (in my case its value is -240). Later on the server side (which runs in utc time) I try to update some db stored utcDate doing something like:

```
var userDate = moment(utcDate).utcOffset(offset)
```

My issue is the following: 
if I run my code as above described I get no effects:

- `utcDate:  20151001 012421 +0000`
- `userDate: 20151001 012421 +0000`

If I flip the offset sign I get:

- `utcDate:  20151001 012421 +0000`
- `userDate: 20151001 052421 +0400`

I'm clearly doing something wrong (even if my expectation was that the first version was correct), do you have any hint?

On client-side I'm using moment.js v2.10.6 while on the server-side moment-timezone.js v0.4.0 and moment.js v2.10.6

Comment: And what do you do with `userDate` after you apply the offset?  You are probably calling `toDate`, `valueOf`, `unix`, or other methods that reflect the instant rather than the wall-time.

Comment: Also, remember "time zone != offset".  If you store the user's *current* offset and later apply it to an arbitrary point in time, it may very well be the wrong offset for that time.  Time zones can change offsets for daylight saving time, and for other various reasons.

Comment: @MattJohnson actually I just `.format(...)` to print out the results. The results that I reported above are printed doing: `console.log('utcDate: ' + moment(utcDate).format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ'));
console.log('userDate: ' + moment(utcDate).utcOffset(offset).format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ'));`. The `utcDate` is without offset.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The main issue is that you are passing the offset as a string instead of a number.

```
moment.utc("2015-10-01 01:24:21").utcOffset("-240").format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
// "20151001 012421 +0000"

moment.utc("2015-10-01 01:24:21").utcOffset(-240).format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
// "20150930 212421 -0400"
```

When you have an offset in terms of minutes, then you must use the numeric form.  You can always convert it:

```
moment.utc("2015-10-01 01:24:21").utcOffset(+"-240").format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
// "20150930 212421 -0400"
```

Moment does allow for offsets to be passed as strings, but it expects them to be in one of the ISO8601 formats:  either `[+/-]HH:mm` or `[+/-]HHmm`.

```
moment.utc("2015-10-01 01:24:21").utcOffset("-04:00").format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
// "20150930 212421 -0400"
```

Additionally, note that I used `moment.utc(...)` to parse the input string.  You just used `moment(...)` which will use the *local* time zone unless the time zone is explicit or if you pass a `Date` object instead of a string.  It will also leave the `moment` object in "local mode", so your `utcDate` output would be wrong unless the time zone of the machine was actually set to UTC.

Lastly, don't forget "Time Zone != Offset".  You can't assume that the offset you obtained is valid for all dates.  If you need to project a date to to the user's time zone, you have to actually know the time zone, such as `America/New_York`.  You can use these with the moment-timezone plugin.

Comment: I just figured out that this is exactly my error, I did not `parseInt` and I was confused by the fact that it worked in one direction and not in the other while `offset` was a string! Thank you!

Comment: @Matt could you helo me in here please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330037/timezone-of-momentjs-does-not-change