# Timezone of momentjs does not change

Tags: javascript, typescript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have something like this:
my input date is `23.01.2021 00:00` and i select `America/New_York` and i add it to the momentjs like this

```
const inputWithTimezone = input + timeZoneUtcFormatt;// e.g. 23.01.2021 00:00 +(-05:00)
  const patterns = [moment.ISO_8601, timestampPattern + 'Z'];
        parsedMoment = moment(inputWithTimezone, patterns,false));
```

if printing the `'parsedMoment'` now, it shows `(Central European Standard Time)` but i changed it by adding the utc number `(-5)` why it does not change the timezone accordignally to `america/new_york`?

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "23.01.2021 00:00-05:00", _f: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mmZ", _strict: false, _tzm: -300, …}
_d: Sat Jan 23 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
_f: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mmZ"
_i: "23.01.2021 00:00-05:00"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_offset: -300
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_strict: false
_tzm: -300
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Hi.  See the linked duplicate for details about Moment's internal structure.  But primarily - you should not use it.  All fields that start with an underscore (`_`) should be off limits.  Use the various functions Moment provides and it will work correctly as designed per the design of those functions.

Comment: Additionally, consider using a different library (or no library).  See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/